# why and when use recompose branch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I've searched around and after reading some stuff, I still didn't get when I use `recompose` `branch` over `if-else` statement in react or why even use it?
can anyone mention a good source or explain it?
thanks

Answer (score 6):

It can be used instead of `if..else` or ternary operator where function composition is preferred. Recompose provides [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) for React components. As other [Recompose higher-order components](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#higher-order-components), `branch` HOC can be composed with `compose`:

```
const fooPredicate = ({ type }) => (type === 'foo');
const FooHOC = Comp => props => <Comp ...props>Foo</Comp>;
const BarHOC = Comp => props => <Comp ...props type="bar">Bar</Comp>;
const FooOrBarHOC = branch(fooPredicate, FooHOC, BarHOC);
const SomeHOC = compose(BazHOC, FooOrBarHOC);
const SomeExampleComponent = SomeHOC(ExampleComponent);
```

All functions involved in `SomeExampleComponent` are reusable and can be tested and used separately from each other.

In case the case is simple and these functions aren't expected to be used with any component except `ExampleComponent`, it can be simplified to:

```
const SomeExampleComponent = BazHOC(props => (
  props.type === 'foo'
  ? <ExampleComponent ...props>Foo</ExampleComponent>
  : <ExampleComponent ...props type="bar">Bar</ExampleComponent>
));
```

Answer (score 2):

***branch*** from ***recompose*** is one of the best way to avoid if-else in your components

```
branch(
   condition,
   leftHOC,
   rightHOC
)(MyComponent)
```

if the condition evaluates to true then

> *MyComponent* is passed to the *leftHOC* else it is passed to the *rightHOC*

Suppose you have to show a loading state till the time data is not available then we can also use ***renderComponent*** from ***recompose***

```
branch(
   props=>props.loading,
   renderComponent(Loader),
   myComponent=>myComponent,
)(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

While Estus answer is good enough and answered how used instead of if..else or ternary operator, I like to mention one another of use cases of branch that we using in our project, when we want to render a component within another component based on some conditions with help of renderComponent() which is useful in combination with branch() ( In our project Usually we use it to render dumb components, modals components , etc )

```
branch<WrappedProps>(
  props => props.success,
  renderComponent(ShowSuccessModal)
)
```

So in this example whenever `props.success` in our container became true, the modal component will rendered.